# How to check for functionalty with multiple threads working without synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider this code:

```
public class test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {

            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Out.println("Counter" +" "+ i);
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}
```

}

This code is susposed to complete this task:

Implement a program in which a thread increments a counter (static field) 1000000 times. Another thread should immediately output the same counter without waiting for the end of the first thread.

Is my code right? The reason why I am asking is because the output is always 0,and I am not sure if that is right.I'm confused as how to check for functionalty of a code when there is no synchronization in play.

Comment: the `i` in thread 1 and the `i` in thread 2 are not the same. You probably meant `for(i = 0; i<1000000; i++)` (without the `int` bit which hides the local variable).

Comment: You said "static field", but there is no static field. There is an "i", local to "main" which you're accessing in t2 and there is an "i" that's local to t1. You never increment the "main" "i".

Comment: Oh, right okay I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Comment: If the output is always 0 I think that's ok, but `x` is not static, as Ben pointed out.  You might have a local capture of `x` which is probably not what you want. (I don't see a problem with `i`, I think there's been an edit.)

Comment: Yea that is what happens.

Comment: @saka1029 I know - that's the next step :-)

Comment: Maybe a hint on how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code is missing the required `static` field (e.g. `i` in the code given below).

```
class Main {
    // Counter
    static int i = 0;   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Counter" + " " + i);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Counter 8588
```

Comment: Oh, I see now, Thank you !